# How to Autosort a Userform Entry

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a question on how to automatically sort information as it is being submitted into a table via a userform.

I have tried the following code, but get errors. Because I'm new to Excel coding, I just can't figure out how to make this work:

```
Dim LR As Integer
LR = Range("A1:E1").End(xlUp).Row
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("A1:BB" & LR).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

**Header Image**

[image: Header Information]

**UserForm Image**

[image: UserForm]

The userform itself works perfectly fine. I'd like to sort via descending order in the date column.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Qualify the exact sheet and range you want to work with.
2. Clear the sort each time and re-apply the sort.
3. Get the last used range of data before setting the sort range. (The way you set `LR` will always be the 1st row.)

Like this:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    Dim LR As Long, rng As Range

    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:BB" & LR)

    With ws.Sort

        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With

End With


Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: This is a very basic question, but how do I qualify the range?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for embedding the pictures, I was having a hard time figuring that part out.

Comment: @VictorBroccoli - what is the error and on what specific line?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class.

When I go to the debug, the "With rang.Sort" is highlighted.

Comment: @VictorBroccoli - If you look at my code, it says `rng.Sort` (**emphasis on the rng**). I point this out because in your comment you have **rang**.Sort. Make sure it says **rng** in your code and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error.

I think I may have inputted the ranges earlier in your code wrong. 

'code'     LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:BB" & LR)

    With rng.Sort

        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=.Range("A1:A" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

Comment: @VictorBroccoli - does your data start in row 1?

Comment: There are headers in row 1, data starts in row 2.

I changed references in there from A1 to A2, but get the same error. My data encompasses A-E.

Comment: sorry @VictorBroccoli. I retested and found the issue. See my updated code.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and patience!